# svchost high CPU/memory and wuauclt high memory on each startup

Tags: windows-xp, memory, cpu

Every time I start up this windows XP laptop (lenovo t60), the svchost and wuauclt processes take up ~200,000k memory each. in addition, svchost takes ~50% of cpu power.

Is there any way to alleviate this?

this happens every time. I can end both processes but that has caused problems with wifi connection.

Comment: wuauclt = Windows update. because Microsoft doesn't provide new updates for XP you can disable the Windows update service completely. But you should update to a supported OS.

Comment: Yeah, it is just an old laptop that I found and wanted to ensure was working so maybe I could surf the web or something if my other computer was broken. Thanks for letting me know